# How do I switch between windows of applications when ` is in a shifted position?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

In the [What's new page for 11.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whats-new#application-switching) it says that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (grave accent) can be used to switch between windows of applications:

[image: Screenshot from the What's new page for 11.10. Switch between windows of applications with Alt+` (Grave).]

This sounds inconvenient on my keyboard because:

1. <kbd>`</kbd> is shifted (I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> (accute accent) to access it, and
2. <kbd>`</kbd> is located left of <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (so it's far from <kbd>Alt</kbd> and this makes the combination hard to press with one hand).

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd>, which should be equivalent to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> on my keyboard, nothing happens. So, how do I use this feature with my keyboard, that is, how do I switch between windows of applications with my keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The What's new page seems to not tell the whole truth when it says that the key combination for switching between windows of application is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (grave accent) because this is only true for the keyboards that has <kbd>`</kbd> placed above <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The key combination to switch between windows of applications is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[The key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>]. On my keyboard the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd> is <kbd>§</kbd> and the key combination and thus the key combination to switch between windows of applications is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>§</kbd>.