# How to use Alt + GraveAccent on non-US keyboard?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114578/what-is-the-grave-button) reveals that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> switches windows *within* a program just like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between open programs. *Wow neat,* thought I, *I've always wondered why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> didn't do this the way Windows does.*

**Problem:

On my non-US keyboard layout, the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) is not above the Tab key. It's a [dead key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) next to Backspace.** For one thing the placement of <kbd>`</kbd> makes it really cumbersome to type; and second, it doesn't work because it's a dead key.

I'd like this to work. How can I either:

- reassign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [whatever key is above Tab in **my** layout]<sup>1)</sup>, or
- make the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch between open programs *and windows* (like in MS Windows)?

---

<sup>1) I'm using a Danish (DK) layout, but this likely affects *many* non-US layouts so a generic answer would help more people.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, [I found an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66762/5786) *after* posting the above: Apparently the shortcut is not the grave-accent specifically but rather "whatever key is above Tab in your current layout" -- exactly as I wanted!

Fascinating!