# Why isn't the Alt+` shortcut working on my international keyboard?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

According to [How to use Alt + GraveAccent on non-US keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114815/how-to-use-alt-graveaccent-on-non-us-keyboard), the Unity shortcut to switch between windows of the same application is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (whichever key is above <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

It doesn't work in my DELL-SK8115 keyboard with Brazilian ABNT2 layout. It's like the key is broken (i.e. pressing the combination has the same effect of pressing only <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Also, if it helps, the same key (but in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> combination) doesn't work in Sublime Text 2, either.

Answer (score 8):

#### To change the so-called <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, which switch between multiple windows of one application, to any custom key combination:

1. [Click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) to install the *Compiz Settings Manager* (CCSM) using the Software Center

   - Or install it from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` from the terminal
2. Start it from the Dash or by typing `ccsm` from the terminal.

   > **Statutory Warning:** *Compiz Config Settings Manager* is an advanced tool and one tiny mistake, typo or an accidental click of the mouse can leave your desktop unusable, requiring time and effort to fix it. Please be very careful and follow instructions...thanks. **If you mess up, please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70836/58612) on how to fix things.**
3. Type "Unity" in the filter box on the left, and click on the Ubuntu Unity Plugin:

   [image]
4. Click on the Switcher Tab on top, and

   [image]

   - Look for the *Key to flip through windows in the switcher* entry near the bottom (scroll down if necessary)
   - Click on the <kbd>Disabled</kbd> button next to it
   - Check the *Enabled* box on the "Edit Key" popup
   - The keys will show, and click on the <kbd>Grab key combination</kbd> button
   - Press the keyboard shortcut combination *you do want to use* and this will appear beneath the box.
   - Click on OK, and this shortcut will now show in place of the *Disabled* button
   - The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is now remapped. To do the same for the reverse <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut, repeat step 4 for the *Key to flip through windows in the switcher* entry, or you can just leave it disabled.

Finally, close CCSM and if you no longer need it, please consider uninstalling it.

Comment: There's no "swicther" where it should be. I tried googling "switcher tab missing from ccsm", but nothing blatantly useful showed up. I also made sure I had the latest version installed from apt-get. I'm using 11.04, is this a problem?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida: Yes, it is. This works on 12.04, it *may* on 11.10, and apparently does not on 11.04. Sorry, but you may have to upgrade to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 14.04 you also need to disable in  `ccsm->desktop wall->Bindings->Move within wall->Move next`

Comment: I see that this 'Move next' is already 'disabled' by default. So, just to be really explicit, do you mean simply to make sure its 'Enabled' checkbox is unchecked, so that is shows a 'Disabled' button in the list shown in the 'Bindings' tab?